# Access Chrome plugins list from webpage via Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, navigator

I created a webpage and would like to execute some code only if the last version of a plugin is installed. In Firefox it is possible to see the version of a plugin via navigator.plugins, in Chrome it is not possible and unfortunately the version is not fully specified into the name/description. Any ideas on how else can I get this?

I wanted to use the way of the page chrome:plugins, which deals directly with the PluginsDOMHandler, but it seems to be very difficult: apparently you have to deal with C++ objects, but I don't know exactly how... Maybe something like js-ctypes (used with Mozilla)?

I read all the already present questions about Chrome plugins, but couldn't find the solution. Thanks in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that navigator.plugins is not a part of any specification. It is free will of vendors to add it to the browser. 
Chrome does not have 'version' key in Plugin object so cu can try your best guess from plugin name (like "Shockwave Flash 16.0 r0").

Furthermore notice a note from [Mozilla Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorPlugins.plugins). Plugins array may not be visible for you as a privacy measure. You may query for particular plugin but you will not see all of them.

Either way you can only use name of a plugin in chrome and try to guest plugins version from it.

Comment: Yes, I saw in some cases the name contains already the version, those cases are already solved. But in the current case the name contains just the part of the version before the dot, instead I need to distinguish between two versions whose difference is the digit after the dot.